# Microsoft Graph Access Token from ADFS 2016

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs

Is it possible to obtain a Microsoft Graph bearer token to make calls as the user to graph from a onprem adfs server or do you need to authenticate the user against a Azure AD and get the token from there?

Comment: Would it work for you to use MSAL.NET with Integrated Windows Authentication:  https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa ? The sample is calling the graph: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2

Comment: The key of the question is regarding an on prem adfs server. Is that example possible to run using calls to the local adfs instead of Azure AD?